# Image carousel translate calculations

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to create an image carousel, but I'm having trouble with calculating the right translate values.

Basically what I'm going for is, if the current image is not the first or the last, it should look exactly like the the second slide ( centered and with parts of the previous and next slide ). If the current slide is the first image, it should show a part of next slide on the right ( this works ). Finally, if the current slide is the last, it should show a part of the previous slide, exactly like the first slide, but on the left side.

There's something I'm missing with the translate values, but I can't figure out what. Or is there maybe a better way of achieving this ?

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slides');
const transitionBy = 85;
var currSlide = 0;

setInterval(function() {     
 if (currSlide > slides.length - 1) {
    currSlide = 0;
  } else {
    slider.style.transform = `translate(-${transitionBy * currSlide}%)`;
  currSlide++;
  }
}, 1500);
```

Code can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0e98d2mz/3/